# Series involving gamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

In the study of gamma incomplete function

does any know how to solve

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\Gamma(k+s+1)}$

Comment: What do you mean by "solve" a quantity? Do you mean evaluate it? WolframAlphe gives the answer as $e(1-\Gamma(s,1)/\Gamma(s))$ in terms of the incomplete and complete Gamma functions.

Comment: The value of limit of the sum

Comment: You have the answer as given by Greg Martin. What else do you want ?

Comment: I don't pretend nothing. I answer because I'm polite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\;\infty } {{1 \over {\Gamma \left( {s + 1 + k} \right)}}}  = \sum\nolimits_{k = s}^{\;\infty } {{1 \over {\Gamma \left( {1 + k} \right)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\;\infty } {{1 \over {k!}}}  - \sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\;s} {{1 \over {k!}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = e - e\left( {{1 \over e}\sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\;s} {{1 \over {k!}}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = e\left( {1 - Q\left( {s,1} \right)} \right) = e\left( {1 - {{\Gamma \left( {s,1} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( s \right)}}} \right) \cr} 
$$
where:
 - the summation is intended in the definition as [Antidifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum);
 - $Q(s,z)$ is the [Regularized Upper Incomplete Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables), which is known to represent
the ratio of the partial to complete expansion of $exp(z)$ (it follows from its functional definition).

In another way, through the definition of [Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables)
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\;\infty } {{1 \over {\Gamma \left( {s + 1 + k} \right)}}}
  = {1 \over {\Gamma \left( {s + 1} \right)}}\sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\;\infty } {{1 \over {{{\Gamma \left( {s + k + 1} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {s + 1} \right)}}}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {s!}}\sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\;\infty } {{1 \over {\left( {s + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}}
  = {1 \over {s!}}\sum\nolimits_{k = 0}^{\;\infty } {{{1^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } } \over {\left( {s + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } }}} {1 \over {k!}} =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {s!}}{}_1F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   {s + 1}  \cr 
 } \;} \right|\;1} \right) \cr} 
$$
we get a [Confluent Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) computed at $x=1$, which confirms the above (re. e.g. to [Wolfram Function site](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/03/01/04/01/))